# Help with Convergent Series and using the right convergent tests

Tags: real-analysis

I have some questions on convergence that I can't seem to make much progress with. I'd just like a hint on which way to go about them.

> Which of the following series are convergent?
>   1.$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n-n}{3^n+n^2}$$ 2. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!}$$ 3. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn^k}{1+2^n}^*$$ 4. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)(x+1)^n}{(n+1)2^n}$$ Consider all possible values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$

*Not sure whether this is a typo and is meant to be $n^n$ not $n^k$

I used the ratio test on 2. and got $$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right |=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^n=e$$ Since $e>1$, $a_n$ diverges. However I need some pointers on the rest of the questions, we have learnt the ratio test, comparison and integral comparison test, absolute convergence and the $n$th root test.

Comment: 3. $n^k/(1+2^n)$ is decreasing from some point for every $n$, so it is converging.1. the ratio test

Comment: The Ratio Test certainly works on 2), but it is overkill. A *glance* at the expression shows that the terms do not have limit $0$, so we have divergence.

Comment: How do you mean the terms do not have limit zero?

Comment: "How do you mean the terms do not have limit zero?" Well, isn't $n^n$ (much) larger than $n!$?

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. Here $a_n=\frac{n^n}{n!}\ge 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks

Comment: In 3), if it is $k$ one can use the Ratio Test to conclude convergence However, if it is $n^n$, the terms do not go to $0$, so we have divergence. In 4) Ratio Test (or Root Test) works fine. Except we must deal separately with $x=-3$ and $x=1$. For these the terms do not have limit $0$.

Comment: For 2 see also: [$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}$ converges or diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417127)

Answer (score 0):

For 1) See $a_n<\frac{2^n}{3^n}$ So by Comparison test you are done.

For 3) Use Leibnitz test.
for 4) $R=2$. Calculate $\lim \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Where $a_n=\frac{(n+1)^k}{1+2^{n+1}}$