# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{n!}$$

It is a convergent or divergent series? Explain how.

I am getting infinite value as $n$ tends to infinity. I have applied the ratio test and higher ratio test.

Comment: The ratio test is overkill. This series doesn't even get past the divergence test.

Comment: Using no tests whatsoever, you can tell that it will diverge just by plugging in values for $n>1$. The numerator will always be $n*n*\cdots$ while the denominator will always be smaller: $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots$.

Comment: @WaveX Technically, that is an application of the *divergence test*.  :P

Comment: @Xander Henderson Yea I guess that's true, it has been well over a year since I've last looked at infinite series :)

Comment: Phrasing? :) Any question of the form "Is it convergent or divergent?" can be answered immediately with a resounding "yes."

Comment: @ClementC. While correct, that is unlikely to be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Note that

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^n}{n!}}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}{n^n(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n(n+1)}=\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n\;.$$

Answer (score 5):

The numerator grows faster than the denominator. For any value of $n>1$, we have $$n^n>n!$$ because they are both products of $n$ factors, but on the LHS, each factor equals $n$, and on the RHS, every factor but one is smaller than $n$. Therefore, for $n>1$, we have $a_n=\frac{n^n}{n!}>1$. Since $a_n\not\to 0$, the series cannot converge, by the divergence test.

In fact, the terms in this sum grow without bound, but even without that, we have shown that the series diverges.

Comment: It is enough to argue that $n^n>n!$ implies that $\frac{n^n}{n!}>1$ cannot converge to zero.

Comment: True. Are you saying I should edit my answer?

Comment: No, unless you feel it makes the answer clearer.

Comment: Yes, the terms are greater than $1$ for $n>1,$ but this does not imply they grow without bound. (They do grow without bound, but you did not show it, and you don't need it.)

Comment: Of course it doesn't imply that they grow without bound, but nobody said it does.

Answer (score 2):

This series is diverge since $\lim_\infty\dfrac{n^n}{n!}=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Wen's answer,

$$\rho=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\frac{n+1}{n}\bigg)^n = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n = e $$

and since $e > 1$, the series diverges by the ratio test.